# @aar' is not a valid maven coordinate

Tags: android, gradle

Android studio upgraded my gradle wrapper to gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all and seems to have broken the build. Getting the following error.

```
Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError: 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b:@aar' is not a valid maven coordinate.
```

The dependancy is in my gradle script as an implementation and the arr is in my libs folder.

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b@aar'
}
```

Has anyone else come accross this error?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same problem this morning. [There's a Github issue that throws more light on the situation.](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2370) It seems to be an Android Studio bug.

Comment: Its a studio issue. For me everything was working fine till last studio 3.0 canary update. seeing this issue after studio update without any change in any file

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** studio update 3.0 canary 6 has solved it.

OLD:
So I was facing the same issue (could be like yours) after the canary update.
I had an `aar` file in the `libs` directory added as a dependency.

this is what it was before

```
compile(name: 'materialbarcodescanner-release', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

this is what solved it

```
 compile('com.edwardvanraak:materialbarcodescanner-release@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

basically added the '{packagename}:{filename}@arr' instead of the usual convention.